# How can I read a local file in Cloud Code as a string?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse Cloud Code.

My system has a welcome message. I use MailGun to send it.

The problem I have is that the message now is an HTML file, so I would like to let the HTML file in my server, read it using Cloud Code and pass that info to MailGun.

Can I read a local text file using Cloud Code and have it in my program as a string?

Should I save that file in my public folder or in the same folder than my cloudcode program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not confident with MailGun, but I believe it should work like **MailChimp** or **Mandrill**. If so, you should be able to store on **MailGun** your whole HTML template and just have some template_vars to complete.

This is a sample code of our own way to send mail with HTML thanks to the Mandrill system

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMailTemplate", function(request, response) {
    var emails = request.params.emails;
    var template_name = request.params.template_name;
    var template_merge_content = request.params.template_merge_content;
    var subject = request.params.subject;
    var Mandrill = require('cloud/mandrillTemplateSend.js');
    if (subject === undefined) {
        subject = 'Mail sent by Mandrill';
        body = subject;
    }
    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) {
        Mandrill.initialize(config.get('Mandrill_key'));
    }).then(function() {
        _.each(emails, function(email) {
            Mandrill.sendTemplate({
                template_name: template_name,
                template_content: [{
                    name: template_merge_content.username,
                    content: ''
                }],
                message: {
                    text: '',
                    subject: subject,
                    from_email: 'contact@yourdomain.com',
                    to: [{
                        email: email,
                        name: template_merge_content.username
                    }],
                    merge_vars: [{
                        rcpt: email,
                        vars: template_merge_content
                    }],
                },
                async: false
            });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        response.success('Success');
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

This object `template_merge_content` is quiet important. It's an object where is saved all the dynamic vars which are send to complete your HTML mail.

According to http://blog.mailgun.com/transactional-html-email-templates/ it seems you have same kind of method to send your mail.

So final advice would be to NOT store your HTML template within any Parse's class, or to save it within https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Config.html

Comment: That's a good idea! I tested and it works. Only a small detail, in my templates I added a variable called *|USERNAME|* and it seems it only works when use template_content and global_merge_vars, both. It doesn't have any sense. If I remove template_content, sending the message fails, if I remove global_merge_vars, I don't see that the variable has the correct value. This is very strange. Any idea? Thanks.